# How to properly set xpaths in import.io for scraping

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, import.io

I am trying to setup an extractor in Import.io and I am having difficulty getting the API to publish. Each time it tells me it can't publish the API and to maybe try using xpaths. So after some further research, I found that the xpath for the title links found on a craig's list page are held in a span tag.
The tag is as follow:

```
span[@class='pl']
```

I've tried setting the following in the xpath area of import.io for a field

```
//span[@class='pl']
```

but to no avail. No matter what I seem to try, I can't actually get the API to publish. While I am able to get the data to export to a dataset, I would really like to get an API to publish.

I am wondering if anyone has had any success using import.io to do some minor scraping of craigs list? And if so, what were the steps in order to get the API to publish properly?

Also, as a side note, I have read some articles on Scrapy, but I know nothing about python, how to install it, and run it, even tho I did find a specific piece of code that is directly related to this question. Anyone have any insight on how I can get Import.io to publish the API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So for anyone else looking for the answer to this question, the way to set the proper xpath for scraping titles on Craig's List using Import.io is by setting the advanced xpath override to the following:

```
.//span[@class='pl']/.
```

Now my issue is about 403 errors being returned from Craig's List - meaning forbidden.